# Linux: Automatically switch to external monitor (VGA)

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, display, xorg, vga

I've got an eeePC with a really tiny monitor, so whenever I go (home, faculty, parent's home, friend's home, ...) I attach it to any external monitor I can find.

If it matters my system is like this:

- Archlinux
- Linux 2.6.36
- Xorg 7.6

  - X server 1.9.2
- Intel Corporation Mobile 945GME Express Integrated Graphics Controller (fully accelerated by `intel` modules)

When I boot up the system, it uses the integrated monitor (`LVDS1`) only, and I have to manually manually switch to the external monitor (`VGA1`) using `xrandr`.

Is it possible to configure my Xorg (or whatever) so that it uses the `VGA1` output if present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Here's how I did it in my `/~.xinitrc` file:

```
xrandr -q | grep "VGA1 connected" && \
  xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1680x1050 --left-of LVDS1
```

This assumes you start your X via "startx" or that you select to run the custom xinit script at gdm/kdm/whatever. 
You can also modify this in a way that your preferred mode is first filtered out from the xrandr output.